# What type of permissions should a user's home directory and files have?

Tags: linux, permissions, security, users, home

I'm working with a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 and I've just added a new user:

```
useradd -m testuser
```

I thought that the `-m` flag to create a home directory for users was pretty standard, but now that I've taken a closer look I'm a little confused:

By default the new directory that was just created shows up as:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 testuser testuser 4.0K May 20 20:24 testuser
```

With the `g+r` and `o+r` permissions that means every other user on the system can not only `cd` to that user's home directory, but also see what is stored there.

When reading over some documentation for suPHP it recommends setting the permissions as `711` or `drwx--x--x` which is how it would make the most sense to me.

I noticed that I can change the permissions on the files inside `/etc/skel` and they are set correctly when creating new users with `useradd -m` but changing the permissions on the `/etc/skel` directory itself does not seem to have any effect on the new directories that are created for users in `/home/`

- So - what type of permissions should a user's home directory and files have - and *why*?
- If I wanted permissions to be different for `useradd -m` - like the `711` / `drwx--x--x` as I saw mentioned, how is one to do that? Must you create the user and then run `chmod` ?

Comment: leave a reason if you downvote

Comment: Have you looked at the man page of `useradd`? If you are on Ubuntu and want to use the commandline you should be using `adduser`. (BTW I did not downvote, but not finding the -K option yourself in the help/man page could indicate little research for others as you don't seem to be a complete Unix newbie)

Comment: @Anthon - yup. I missed the `-K` part in man - but I did look over it before asking (not well enough). However the `man` page still does not explain **why** it says `If not specified, the mask will be initialized to 022.` Also, it does not seem that `adduser` provides any other benefit besides an interactive prompt based system - it, too, creates the home directories by default as 755.

Comment: adduser (its deluser counterpart)  does things like deleting a users 'private' group which I don't think adduser does. It also makes it more easy to make a normal or system user with the uid in the right number range. I recommend you look at what can be specified for `adduser` in `/etc/adduser.conf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the creation of the home directory behave differently do

```
useradd -m -K UMASK=0066 testuser
```

Giving **other** no access at all should be safe.

Comment: Interesting. So without that I guess it just is using the default `umask` set in the shell session ?

Comment: @cwd: that is correct

Comment: @cwd  Regarding the public_html thing you asked about in Ignacio's response: I'd make  the owning group something that the apache user is a member of, and still get away w/o access for other

Comment: That sounds good to me. I will give it a shot. Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't that umask be 0077 instead of 0066?

Answer (score 2):

I've had no problems setting home directories as 0700 as a base, and then opening them up more little by little as required.

Comment: Don't they need to be at least 711 if they contain something like a `public_html` folder, or if one of the subdirectories is a shared / group folder? Also, can you set them as your `700` by default somehow with the `useradd -m` command ? Also - why would Ubuntu even think it is OK to default to 755?

Comment: That would be part of the "as required". On my (Fedora) system the umask can be set in `/etc/login.defs`; Ubuntu must have something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are posting this in security I will take a bait. This is how is done in by default in OpenBSD

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 predrag  predrag  512 May 20 23:00 predrag
```

My account has been created on the boot. You see that by default a separate group is created and I am logged in as a member of that group. That first account is by default member of the wheel  group but not for example member of operator group which means that I could not shutdown the computer.

Note that by default new users on OpenBSD are added with *adduser* interactive Perl script which also creates the home directory with correct permission and many other things.

This is what RedHat does by default

```
drwx------. 48 predrag     predrag  4096 May 20 17:51 predrag
```

I am System Admin on that computer and that is regular account created by default for root user. RedHat doesn't have a custom script but some values of useradd are pre-populated with default values.

Answer (score 2):

You should set `DIR_MODE` in `/etc/adduser.conf` and use the `adduser` command as recommended in the `man` page for `useradd` on your system:

```
adduser testuser
```

If you do not want to make changes to the original `/etc/adduser.conf` (or need different setups) you can make changes in a copy and use `adduser --conf <yourconf>`

Comment: Thx - this helps with the second part of the question.